# How to avoid executing the else part of a conditional statement?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a function that is called to retrieve transactions by a specified start and end date. I am now updating this function to also return ALL transactions(start/end date are null) for certain cases.

When start and end date are null (which are properties of the TransactionsCriteria class) I need the last code block in the snippet below executed. I can't wrap that snippet of code in an if statement since I need it executed for other cases as well, when start and end date are NOT null.

How do I accomplish implementing this logic with the below code block?

Thank you.

```
public async Task<(int total, List<Transaction> records)> GetAllTransactionsAsync(int fundId, TransactionsCriteria criteria)
    {
        IQueryable<Transaction> transactions = _db.Transactions.Include(t => t.DepositSource).Include(t => t.WithdrawalSource).Include(t => t.ReconciliationReport).Where(t => t.FundId == fundId);
        if (criteria.UseClearedDate)
        {
            transactions = transactions.Where(t => t.ReconciliationReport != null && (t.ReconciliationReport.DateCreated.Date >= criteria.StartDate.Date
                                               && t.ReconciliationReport.DateCreated.Date <= criteria.EndDate.Date));
        }
        if (criteria.Reconcile)

        {
            transactions = transactions.Where(t =>
                                              t.Date.Date <= criteria.EndDate.Date);
        }
        else
        {
            transactions = transactions.Where(t =>
                                              t.Date.Date >= criteria.StartDate.Date
                                              && t.Date.Date <= criteria.EndDate.Date);
        }

        transactions = transactions.Where(t => (criteria.Statuses.Contains(t.ReconciliationId == null ? t.IsVoided ? TransactionStatus.Void : TransactionStatus.Outstanding : TransactionStatus.Cleared))
                                          && criteria.Sources.Contains(t.TransactionSource) && criteria.Types.Contains(t.TransactionType));
```

Comment: `else` statement will not be executed if `criteria.StartDate == null && criteria.EndDate == null`

Comment: I am utterly confused. "_In this case when start and end date are null I don't want the else statement executed._" It won't. I don't know what you are trying to ask/explain here. Clearly `if` start and end date are both null, then the if statement block will be executed, but not the `else` statement block. Did you just word your question poorly and i misunderstood you, or are you not knowing what `if (...) {...} else {...}` does? (If the former, please **edit** and clarify your question; if the latter, please spend some more time with C# tutorials/guides covering basic control structures)

Comment: in the if statement of start/end date is null i want this code block rendered. 
 transactions = transactions.Where(t => (criteria.Statuses.Contains(t.ReconciliationId == null ? t.IsVoided ? TransactionStatus.Void : TransactionStatus.Outstanding : TransactionStatus.Cleared))
                                          && criteria.Sources.Contains(t.TransactionSource) && criteria.Types.Contains(t.TransactionType));

Comment: Due to not making a lot of sense, perhaps you could give some test values with expected outcome?

Comment: **Edit** and improve your question. Do not attempt to clarify and expand your question into the comments. That's not what comments are meant for. Describe your problem **in** the question, not in the comments...

Comment: Literally put this English sentence into code: "_If start date is null and (perhaps or instead of and?) end date is null, then get all transactions, otherwise get transactions based on start/end date._" If you can't translate this simple (English) statement into code, you really, really need to spend some more time with C# tutorials/guides covering if/else control structures, in my opnion. But that's just my opinion. Take it or leave it, it's just a comment that doesn't mind to be ignored. ;-)

Comment: "_I can't wrap that snippet of code in an if statement since I need it executed for other cases as well, when start and end date are NOT null._" You are still not making sense. If you want to execute that snippet of code no matter whether start/end data are null or not null, then does it not mean that you basically want to execute that code snippet _always_? Why then do you want to put this code into an `if` or `else` block? Unless you manage to explain your problem in a coherent and logical manner, your question likely won't be answered to your satisfaction...

Answer (score 0):

By virtue of it being an if...else statement, matching the condition `criteria.StartDate == null && criteria.EndDate == null` causes it to enter the **if** block and skip the **else** block.

Comment: correct. My question should be, what code should i put in this if start/end date is null statement. Should I put the code block right underneath this conditional inside this if? That's what I logically want to accomplish. But then the same code block will be executed twice which is probably very incorrect.

Comment: @user11351969, again, if you need to clarify your question, then edit your question. Right now it kinda feels like as if people should just ignore your question above and look for your real question here in the comments. Which would be somewhat silly... ;-)

Comment: Agreed, what you're after is a little vague. Break your problem up into smaller pieces. Identify the different possible criteria combinations for your normal use cases, and also for the potentially funny use cases. For example: If you want to return all the transaction data on the condition that both dates are null then move that if statement to the top, add the where clause and return that immediately. That way you've already handled that condition at the start.